# c# equivalent class for Json string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have Json string, which I have create in jquery. Now I have to Post it on server side. I'm unable to create it's equivalent class in c#.

This is my json String

```
[
    {
        "Option": "Sub Option 0",
        "Value": "Question 0",
        "questions": [
            {
                "Option": "Sub Option 1",
                "Value": "Sub Question for 0",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "Option": "Sub Option 2",
                        "Value": "Sub Question for 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Option": "Sub Option 5",
                        "Value": "Sub Question for 1",
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "Option": "Sub Option 6",
                                "Value": "Sub Question for 5",
                                "questions": [
                                    {
                                        "Option": "Sub Option 7",
                                        "Value": "Sub Question for 6"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Option": "Sub Option 3",
                "Value": "Sub Question for 0"
            },
            {
                "Option": "Sub Option 4",
                "Value": "Sub Question for 0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried like this.

```
public class AnyName
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<AnyName> questions { get; set; }
}
```

My action method which will accept the data

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetQuestion(AnyName allQuestions)
{
    //read all the question here.
    var x = 10;
}
```

Js:

```
var myJson = CreateJsonData(childrenQuestions);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/Home/GetQuestion',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(myJson),
                success: function (result) {

                }
            });
```

I'm getting null at server side . `allQuestions is null`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Also explain how it will answer the OP's question

Comment: The questions at level third is missing in json, may be the cause for your problem.

Comment: Please do set empty array for the "questions" node where its missing. You will surely get solution by deserializing it.

Comment: Ur sending an arrayof anyname to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the casing of the questions property as it is lower cased in the JSON string.  Depending on the JSON serializer being used, you may also try to map it using an attribute, that may be serializer specific, but matching the class property to the expected property name in JSON is a bit more fool proof.

```
public class Question
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}
```

List will generate a JSON array of the Question class and will deserialize properly from a JSON array containing structures that fit the Question class.

Since the JSON structure has a root of a JSON array of questions, you also need to make this change to accept the array:

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetQuestion(List<Question> questions)
{
   //read all the question here.
   var x = 10;
}
```

and discard the `Root` class.  You don't need it based on the JSON structure.

Comment: I have changed It. But still I'm getting null at server side. See the edited question.

Comment: Also, the property 'questions' is lower cased in the JSON string, so do the same in the class

Comment: @AmitKumar One more update.  The signature of the action needs to be changed.

Comment: @Tryee Jackson: i havn't downvoted. I have tried both List as well as simple class. in both case I'm getting null.

Comment: @AmitKumar Please see the latest update to my answer.  Upon further review of your JSON, it looks like you need several changes.

Comment: @Tryee jackson: thanks It's working. but I don't understand why parameter is of type list. ?

Comment: @AmitKumar List<T> serializes to and from an array type in JSON.  You could also use array and other array like types.  I selected List<T> arbitrarily.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any name

```
public class AnyName
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<AnyName> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

So your type to deserialize will be `List<AnyName>`, for ex,

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AnyName>>(json);
```

Comment: I'm getting null at server side.

Comment: @AmitKumar See my updated answer.  You have a casing problem with the questions property.

Comment: @AmitKumar Without your server side code, it is hard to say anything. Your WebMethod's parameter should be `List<AnyName>`

Comment: @EZI: I have added my server side as well as client code in question. see there.

Comment: @AmitKumar `GetQuestion`s parameter should be  `List<AnyName>`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the serializer, you may be able to set a different property name. For example, with Json.NET, you can write your property as:

```
[JsonProperty("Questions")]
public List<Questions> SubQuestions { get; set; }
```

See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm